# Contar valores de uma coluna ignorando se o valor já é repetido

Tags: microsoft-excel

Tenho esta seguinte planilha com cada coluna sendo um data.
E em cada data tenho estes seguintes registros, porém eles podem repetir este registro em outras datas para frente.

Como é caso do registro 57544 ela apareceu no dia 30/10, porém apareceu no dia 31/10.

Eu precisava contar a quantidade de registros por coluna removendo os registros que já apareceram em datas anteriores.

Seria quantidade de valores menos duplicadas, conforme a imagem.

Os registros em vermelho é a 1 vez que registro apareceu, ela precisa ser contada

Os registros em amarelo são as duplicações que ocorreram no dia, e precisa ser ignorados na contagem do dia.

As contagens na imagem foram feitos manualmente para ilustrar o problema.

Tentei as formulas de cont.se com procv, porém não obtive resultado.

[image: Excel]

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Comment: Leandro, considerando que a coluna do dia 30/10 que é a base pra que vc compare com as demais colunas esteja na coluna B. Faça a seguinte fórmula matricial.

Comment: {SOMA(CONT.SE($B$2:$B$16;C2:C16))}

Comment: Assim que tiver terminado de digitar a fórmula, pressione ao mesmo tempo as teclas CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, para que o Excel insira as chaves {} e interprete esta fórmula como matricial.

Comment: Testou a solução??